# Change image by Scrolling Percentage instead of Scrolling Pixels

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've gotten some help with some Jquery code to make an image dynamically change 3 times as i scroll further down the page. The code below works as is but as I guess you understand it's not a good thing to rely on pixels since different screens have different resolutions.

Therefore I'd like to change the...

`(pos > 2900 && pos < 3900)`

to something more like...

`(scrollPercent > 25% && scrollPercent < 35%)`

so that the transition works exactly the same on every screen.

```
window.onload = function(){
$("#package1").fadeIn(500);
$(document).scroll(function() {
  var pos = $(document).scrollTop();
  if (pos < 2900) {
    hideAll("package1");
    $("#package1").fadeIn(500);
  }
  if (pos > 2900 && pos < 3900) {
    hideAll("package2");
    $("#package2").fadeIn(500);
  }
    if (pos > 3900 && pos < 5000) {
    hideAll("package3");
    $("#package3").fadeIn(500);
  }
});

function hideAll(exceptMe) {
  $(".package").each(function(i) {
    if ($(this).attr("id") == exceptMe) return;
    $(this).fadeOut(1000);
  });
}}
```

Anyone who got any ideas?

For reference, my work-in-progress page: http://www.johnmorganstudios.se/client-sevn/

Answer (score 0):

What I could recommend for you at this moment would be:

```
var h =document.body.clientHeight;
var i=h/2;
window.scrollBy(0, i);
```

Note: `/2` means `50%` and `/5` means `20%` and so.

So In you case it will be something like:

```
var h=document.body.clientHeight;
var i=h/4, o=h/2.85; // 25% as you said. and o which is gonna be 35%

window.onload = function(){
$("#package1").fadeIn(500);
$(document).scroll(function() {
  var pos = $(document).scrollTop();
  if (pos < i) {
    hideAll("package1");
    $("#package1").fadeIn(500);
}
  if (pos > i && pos < o) {
    hideAll("package2");
    $("#package2").fadeIn(500);
  }
    if (pos > o && pos < 5000) {
    hideAll("package3");
    $("#package3").fadeIn(500);
  }
});

function hideAll(exceptMe) {
  $(".package").each(function(i) {
    if ($(this).attr("id") == exceptMe) return;
    $(this).fadeOut(1000);
  });
}}
```

Note: I have replaced all 2900 to `25%` and 3900 to `35%`.

Good Luck :)

Comment: Hey @mr-jorden, thanks for your input! How would I put in your code in mine for the function to work properly?

Comment: @morganhassel I've updated my answer See the change and if worked click on the answered button.

Comment: Thank you for your extended explanation @mr-jorden! Before I had the option to try your answer out, I found another solution here which seamed to do the trick: http://iwearshorts.com/blog/measuring-user-scroll-with-jquery/